# Filtering object keys inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Let's assume I'm obtaining an array of objects from a Node Repository, for example:

```
results = [
    {
        name: "John",
        surname: "Fool",
        age: 22
    },
    {
        name: "Erik",
        surname: "Owl",
        age: 38
    }
]
```

How can I filter every object taking only the keys I need, for example avoiding 'age' key?

```
filteredResults = [
    {
        name: "John",
        surname: "Fool",
    },
    {
        name: "Erik",
        surname: "Owl",
    }
]
```

I've already obtained this by creating another empty array and populating it by looping on the original one, but in case of large-data this would be heavy.

```
repository.retrieve((error, result) => {
  let filteredData = [];
  result.forEach(r => {
    filteredData.push({
      name: r.name,
      description: r.description,
    });
  });
});
```

In SQL, I would obtain it this way:

```
SELECT `name, description` FROM results;
```

Comment: I'd probably use a library (e.g., lodash) that has something like a `pick` function, or just hack together a quick one of your own (it's quite short).

Comment: Why don't you use MongoDB projections for that? What do you mean by "Node Repository"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform individual elements of the array. And in the callback function use [Object destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to use only the keys you are interested in and return a new object with only those keys.

```js
let results = [
    { name: "John", surname: "Fool", age: 22 },
    { name: "Erik", surname: "Owl", age: 38 }
];

let modified = results.map(({name, surname}) => ({name, surname}));
console.log(modified);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just rebuild the object as you want

```
  { 
    name: rec.name,
    surname: rec.surname
  }
```

```js
const results = [
    {
        name: "John",
        surname: "Fool",
        age: 22
    },
    {
        name: "Erik",
        surname: "Owl",
        age: 38
    }
]

const result = results.map((rec) => {
  return { 
    name: rec.name,
    surname: rec.surname
  }
})


console.log(result)
```

Or [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) fields that is useless

```js
const results = [
    {
        name: "John",
        surname: "Fool",
        age: 22
    },
    {
        name: "Erik",
        surname: "Owl",
        age: 38
    }
]

const result = results.map((rec) => {
  delete rec.age
  return rec
})


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and `reduce` to simplify this, which obviates the need to create a new array.

```js
var results = [ { name: "John", surname: "Fool", age: 22 }, { name: "Erik", surname: "Owl", age: 38 } ];
let keys = ['name', 'surname'];
var filtered = results.map(obj=>
   keys.reduce((acc,curr)=>(acc[curr]=obj[curr],acc), {}));
console.log(filtered);
```

You can also use object destructuring.

```js
var results = [ { name: "John", surname: "Fool", age: 22 }, { name: "Erik", surname: "Owl", age: 38 } ];
var filtered = results.map(({name,surname})=>({name,surname}));
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can tell more about what you will need to perform on the output to get the answer that can help.

Case 1. if your original list will survive and you accept your "modified list" to always follow the original list, you may use a generator to wrap your original object, by always not returning those extra properties.

Case 2. if you really want a query system, you may try using real DB thing such as [levelDB](https://github.com/Level/level)

Case 3. if you need to display the modified list, write a simple wrapper to fit the format of each list item

Case 4. if you need to snapshot the modified list as object, the method you already made is already a very reasonable method

Case 5. if you need to snapshot the modified list as another output, you can try to directly obtain such output rather than making the intermediate object

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).It creates the transformed array.

```js
let arr = [
    {
        name: "John",
        surname: "Fool",
        age: 22
    },
    {
        name: "Erik",
        surname: "Owl",
        age: 38
    }
]

let result = arr.map((elem) => {
  return {
    name: elem.name,
    surname: elem.surname
  }
});

console.log(result);
```